# iPhone's "Add to Home Screen" customization?

Tags: iphone, html, ios

Is it possible to change the background of the "Add to Home Screen"? .. which is typically user initiated from an iPhone app to creates a custom bookmark on the home screen of the iPhone.

Comment: So wait, what does this have to do with [xcode] exactly?  This has more to do with HTML than anything.

Answer (score 2):

Pop this in your `<head>`

```
<rel="apple-touch-icon" href="image.png"/>
```

This will be the thumbnail on the I phone's home screen. The image should be square, with a size of `57x57`

You can also use

```
<rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="image.png"/>
```

If you don't want iOS to add effects to your thumbnail.

Comment: Cheers, but this only does the icon not the "background"?

Comment: I don't think that can be changed. If you have an example of where that is changed - post it here and we can work out how

Comment: hmm... I havent seen any examples but was hoping something could have been done. Oh well. Thanks anyways for your help!